# Billing for externally enabled functionality

Tags: android

I am in the early stages of scoping an app that targets a specific vertical market. It is not consumer orientated. The organisation developing the app has existing web-based products and established infrastructure for registering user accounts and billing for those products, and the app should inter-operate with these products. To that end, I have a few questions:

1) If the app that has functionality that can only be enabled from outside the app (for example, via a separate web site) and where the developer bills the user for doing this:

Q1. Can this App be distributed using Google Play?

Q2. Since enabling the functionality takes place outside of the app, does the developer have to use Google Play's payment system to bill for it?

2) If the app which allows a user to create an item of content on a separate web site, so that they can subsequently modify it on that site and be billed for doing so (eg, a bug tracking app that charges for creating a bug record on a site):

Q3 Does this count as an in-app purchase and require use Google Play's payment system to bill for it?

Where can I find definitive statements from Google on these scenarios? I am only finding material that relates to consumer applications where the purchasing and billing scenario is fairly simple.

Comment: I'm not sure whether your Q touches only the legal aspects or if you also are interested in technical aspects of your potential scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot shed much light on the potential "thou shalst not have any payment methods beside me" aspect of your question, but as per the technical side, the following aspects come to my mind.

- Q1: Technically, the app could either be free on GP and use other payment methods, or it could use the Licensing Validation service.
- Q2: The only secure way of deploying Google Play Licensing is to perform all integrity checks on your own secure server. The app could request the GP LVL info and pass it to your server. You could use the GP LVL user ID (an obfuscated binary app-specific byte string) to identify the user and negotiate with your app any password details you may want to implement. Of course, in this scenario, I would expect the user to feel like he already payed so the registration on the server side should be smoothly integrated. If an "enabling"/"authentication" step is additionally required on the server side, I'm not so sure I'd use the GP LVL.
- Q3: You could use GP IAB V3 consumable in-app purchases for this (or V2 subscriptions but it sounds more like a per-item payment). Again, this is only secure if you generate a per-purchase developerPayload for the buy Intent on your server and validate it when the app looks at the user's purchases. Validation again must take place on your server, or else you'll have to include your app's public key in your app, which is a major step towards your app getting cracked.
- In general, if you have a user management of your own which is to be used, it is important to know that the GP info is relatively anonymous (LVL: obfuscated, IAB V3: no info in the direction of the app at all). So a reliable, use-case oriented binding between "your" accounts and the GP experience would be key here, I'd say.